# Passing Context from wizard . Odoo 14

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I added a wizard model with 2 buttons 'cancel' and 'confirm' ; in the function 'button_validate' in 'stock.picking' model , I want to generate this wizard if quantity_done > product_uom_qty , the function cancel will execute the buttton_validate.
When clicking on confirm button I want to continue execute the rest of function 'button_validate', how can I do it using context ?Any help please??

```
class Wizard(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'wizard.wizard'

    def confirm(self):
        active_id = self.env['stock.picking'].browse(self.env.context.get('active_id', False))

    def cancel(self):
        picking_id = self.env['stock.picking'].browse(self.env.context.get('active_id', False))
        picking_id.button_validate




class Picking(models.Model):
    _inherit = "stock.picking"

    def button_validate(self, is_active_id=False):
        # Clean-up the context key at validation to avoid forcing the creation of immediate
        # transfers.
        ctx = dict(self.env.context)
        ctx.pop('default_immediate_transfer', None)
        self = self.with_context(ctx)

        # Sanity checks.
        pickings_without_moves = self.browse()
        pickings_without_quantities = self.browse()
        pickings_without_lots = self.browse()
        products_without_lots = self.env['product.product']
        for picking in self:


            for move in picking.move_ids_without_package:
                if move.quantity_done > move.product_uom_qty:
                    action = self.env["ir.actions.actions"]._for_xml_id("my_module.action_of_my_wizard")
                    return action



            if not picking.move_lines and not picking.move_line_ids:
                pickings_without_moves |= picking

            picking.message_subscribe([self.env.user.partner_id.id])
            picking_type = picking.picking_type_id
               ........
```